# Time Complexity of function sorted()

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm, time-complexity

I was doing a leetcode problem where i need to use **sorted()** function in python3, but I'm a bit confused about the complexity of this funtion when every element in the array is sorted except one.

Suppose list intervals is already sorted, and i preform this action:

```
intervals.append(new)
sorted(intervals)
```

what's the complexity of this action? Will it still be O(nlog(n)) or O(log(n)), since only one insertion is required?

Answer (score 1):

`O(log(n))` is completely impossible for any sorting algorithm that takes in the whole list since it's already `O(n)` to check if the list is sorted. In this situation where the list is almost sorted python's sorting algorithm, TimSort, is smart enough to be `O(n)`, this is one of the cases the algorithm is optimized for. However, assuming the task is to implement something in `O(log(N))`, you probably want to use binary search, for that look at the stdlib [`bisect`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html) module

Comment: binary search is useful for *finding* an element, but for *inserting* an element -- which seems the asker's case -- it would not help to improve on a O(n) time complexity.

Comment: @trincot That is why I said "implement something in ``O(log(N))``". Yes, insert can't be it, but if the goal is log performance, binary search is the correct pointer.

Comment: @trincot it wouldn't help in the specific case given in the question.  But binary insertion is useful to find the exact insertion point to keep the list sorted after insertion without requiring a separate sorting step.  Unfortunately the insertion step itself is O(n).

Comment: Why "basically"?

Comment: @KellyBundy Because technically I believe the time complexity for anything but a fully sorted list is `O(nlog(n))`, however I doubt that that will be a noticeable effect here. I.e. I can't guarantee that it is actually `O(n)`, but I don't think you will be able to measure a difference.

Comment: It'll just detect and merge the two runs in O(n).

Comment: @KellyBundy Right, changed it.